# phpSpreadSheet library giving error when uploaded to the server

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

I am working on a project, in which XLS file needs to be uploaded to the server and extract its content. When I worked on my localhost it was working perfectly, but after I uploaded the project on the server, `phpSpreadSheet` library started not working. I checked the `error_log` file in the server and noticed that the following error has appeared.

```
PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting '&' or variable (T_VARIABLE) in 'vendor/markbaker/complex/classes/src/operations/add.php'
```

I think that I do not have any error in my code as the library was working in my localhost without errors.

```
 $reader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader('Xlsx');
 $reader->setReadDataOnly(TRUE);

 $spreadsheet = $reader->load(strip_tags($file_path));

 $worksheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();

        $highestRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow();
        $highestColumn = $worksheet->getHighestColumn();

        $data = $worksheet->rangeToArray(
            'A1:' . $highestColumn . '1',
            NULL,TRUE,TRUE
        );
```

Comment: Your code is missing error handling, see: [Error handling](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/reading-files/#error-handling)

Comment: Did you install PhpSpreadsheet using Composer?

Comment: yes, I uploaded using composer

Comment: Try re-uploading your vendor directory. Looks like a file didn't get completely uploaded `vendor/markbaker/complex/classes/src/operations/add.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long search, I solved the issue by upgrading the php version on the server. Php version on the server was 5.4 and it was causing the problem, phpSpreadSheet software requirement shows that supported PHP version is  5.6 or newer.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by simply enabling the xls entension generation.
You can login to your cpanel and search for php version.
Below you will find some checkboxes. Make sure the one with the xls written is ticked and save the changes. Done